# How to slow down a fling animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I was playing with the fling animation based on the grid demo in Flutter Gallery. I made the example below work, but the animation plays very fast. I could barely see it unless I slow it down by using `timeDilation`. Changing the value of velocity doesn't seem to have much effect. Should I look at something else? Thanks!

```dart
import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show timeDilation;

const kLogoUrl =
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dart-lang/logos/master/logos_and_wordmarks/dart-logo.png";

class LogoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  // Leave out the height and width so it fills the animating parent
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
        child: new Image.network(kLogoUrl));
  }
}

class TranslateTransition extends StatelessWidget {
  TranslateTransition({this.child, this.animation});

  Widget child;
  Animation<Offset> animation;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animation,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return new Center(
            child: new Transform(
              transform: new Matrix4.identity()
                ..translate(animation.value.dx, animation.value.dy),
              child: new Container(
                height: 100.0,
                width: 100.0,
                child: child,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        child: child);
  }
}

class LogoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  LogoAppState createState() => new LogoAppState();
}

class LogoAppState extends State<LogoApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<Offset> _flingAnimation;
  AnimationController _controller;

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    timeDilation = 5.0;

    _controller = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
    );

    _flingAnimation = new Tween<Offset>(
      begin: new Offset(-150.0, -150.0),
      end: new Offset(150.0, 150.0),
    )
        .animate(_controller);

    _controller
      ..value = 0.0
      ..fling(velocity: 0.1)
      ..addListener(() {
//        print(_flingAnimation.value);
      });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new TranslateTransition(
        child: new LogoWidget(), animation: _flingAnimation);
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(new LogoApp());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fling` uses a SpringSimulation with default parameters, one of which is the spring constant. Even if you start with velocity zero, a spring will spring at a speed determined by the spring constant. So what's happening is that you're going from 0.0 to 1.0 with a pretty tight critically-damped string.

Also, because you're using a NetworkImage, you don't see anything because the image takes longer to load than the animation takes to run.

If you replace `LogoWidget` with `FlutterLogo`, you'll see what's happening better.

If you want it to go slower, you can use `animateWith` instead of `fling` to pass it a specific `SpringSimulation` with your own custom parameters.

The existence of `fling` is a bit of a historical accident. It's designed to be used primarily with `AnimationController`s with a `lowerBound` and `upperBound` given in pixels, rather than over the 0.0...1.0 default range.